# Increase charset="utf-8" Font size in php/mysql site

Tags: php, mysql, css, utf-8, indic

Please see www.favoritebd.com. Here you can see two language (1) Bangla and (2) English. So to enable Bangla Language I used..

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Issue is Bangla font size, it's smaller than English fonts. So is there anyway to increase **ONLY BANGLA FONT SIZE** or can I use css property/value **like** `charset=utf-8'{ font-size:18px;}`(I don't know is it valid!)

However in my css i used...

```
div.font{ font-size:120%; font-weight:normal;}
```

To increase the Bangla font size but it's also increase English font size but I just want only increase bangla font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use the same utf-8 for both Bangla and English?

Comment: well, how can i do this @Col Shrapnel? can you please give me an example.

Comment: you don't need to do anything. just set utf-8 as the only site encoding.